# Regionale Verteilung der Helligkeit von Schwarzbrot

Tags: regional, reference-request

In meinem Zivildienst wurde mir eines Tages aufgetragen, ***Schwarzbrot*** zu besorgen. Was ich kaufte, sah in etwa so aus:

[image: Schwarzbrot]

Da ich das Brot direkt einräumte, wurde ich nicht direkt kritisiert, sondern es wurde mir beim nächsten Einkauf zwischen Tür und Angel mitgeteilt, dass ich doch dieses Mal nicht so etwas Seltsames mitbringen solle, sondern richtiges Schwarzbrot. Mir blieb nichts übrig, außer zu raten, und so kaufte ich etwas, das wie folgt aussah und das ich als ***Pumpernickel*** bezeichnen würde:

[image: Pumpernickel]

Schließlich wurde ich darüber aufgeklärt, dass mit *Schwarzbrot* in etwa Folgendes gemeint sei, was ich als ***Graubrot*** bezeichnen würde:

[image: Graubrot]

Dieselben Personen stuften Folgendes als *Graubrot* ein. Ich würde es schlichtweg ***Brot*** nennen (oder *trockenen Mampf).*

[image: Brot]

Meine Frage ist nun, ob es irgendwelche **Erhebungen oder ausführliche Beschreibungen der regionalen Verteilung der Bezeichnungen für unterschiedliche Brothelligkeiten** gibt. Im [Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) bin ich nicht fündig geworden. Was ich im Internet finden konnte, behauptet, dass *Graubrot* nur in Österreich als *Schwarzbrot* bezeichnet werde – aber die besagte Geschichte spielte sich in Norddeutschland ab und es gab keinen Grund zu der Annahme, dass einer der Beteiligten eine österreichische Vergangenheit hatte.

Beachte: Dies ist keine Umfrage. Ich bin an weiträumigen Erhebungen interessiert, nicht daran, wie Ihr persönlich Brot kategorisiert.

Comment: Völlig an Deiner Frage vorbei, fiel mir aber trotzdem gerade ein: http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley/2015/04/lexicon_valley_the_etymology_and_history_of_the_word_pumpernickel_with_lexicographer.html

Comment: Ich halte diese Frage für Unsinn, weil es ganz klar ist, dass solche Einordnungsversuche völlig unscharf bleiben werden, da nicht nur regional sondern individuell bzw. von Familie zu Familie unterschiedlich. Das ist in etwa, als ob einer fragt, ab welcher Temperatur heiß anfängt.

Comment: @falkb: Zwar erwarte ich keine völlig scharfe Trennung, aber iauch nicht, dass es völlig unscharf ist. Und selbst wenn dem so sein sollte, wäre das immer noch eine Antwort. Selbst eine Frage nach der regionalen Verteilung der Verwendung von *heiß* sehe ich als berechtigt an, sofern es irgendwelche Hinweise darauf gibt, dass es hier regionale Unterschiede geben könnte. Hier kommt allerdings erschwerend hinzu, dass die Verwendung von *heiß* auch vom Kontext abhängt.

Comment: Übrigens backe ich Brot aus reinem Weizenmehl das in etwa so dunkel aussieht wie in Deinem letzten Bild.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zunächst ein Blick auf die rechtliche Seite. Die drei großen deutschsprachigen Länder haben alle eine offizielle Definition von *Weißbrot*, aber nur Österreich auch eine für *Schwarzbrot*:

- In Deutschland ist *Weißbrot* ein Brot aus mindestens 90% Weizenmehl. ([Deutsches Lebensmittelbuch, Leitsätze für Brot und Kleingebäck](https://www.bmel.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/Ernaehrung/Lebensmittelbuch/LeitsaetzeBrot.pdf?__blob=publicationFile))
- In Österreich ist *Weißbrot* ein Brot „aus Weizenmahl- und -schälprodukten verschiedener Typen“, wobei bis zu 10% Roggenmehl enthalten sein dürfen. *Schwarzbrot* besteht aus Roggen- und Weizenmehl. ([Österreichisches Lebensmittelbuch, B 18 2.1](http://www.lebensmittelbuch.at/backerzeugnisse/backwaren/brot/))
- In der Schweiz ist *Weissbrot* ein Brot ausschließlich aus „vorwiegend aus dem inneren Teil des Getreidekorns“ gewonnenem Weizenmehl und *Halbweissbrot* solches aus nahezu schalenfreiem Weizenmehl. Andere Getreidesorten dürfen nicht enthalten sein. ([Verordnung des EDI über Getreide, Hülsenfrüchte, Pflanzenproteine und deren Erzeugnisse](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/20050167/index.html))

Damit ist es – außer in Österreich – weitgehend den Bäckern und dem allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch überlassen, was sie als *Schwarzbrot* oder *Graubrot* bezeichnen wollen.

Laut dem *Variantenwörterbuch des Deutschen* ist der Begriff *Graubrot* nur in den Gebieten D-Nordost und D-Mittelwest verbreitet und bezeichnet dort ein Mischbrot aus Roggen- und Weizenmehl. D-Nordost besteht dabei etwa aus Mecklenburg-Vorpommern, den nördlichen Teilen von Sachsen-Anhalt und Brandenburg sowie Berlin; zu D-Mittelwest gehören vor allem das Rheinland und Hessen.

Comment: Ich bin in Mecklenburg aufgewachsen. Bei uns gab es Weißbrot, Mischbrot, Schwarzbrot und Pumpernickel. Das Wort "Graubrot" habe ich erst in der Familie meiner Freundin gehört, die aus Sachsen (Raum Borna) kam. "Richtiges" Schwarzbrot ist aus meiner Sicht Roggenbrot, Roggenmischbrot; oft auch noch mit Malz "geschwärzt".

Answer (score 4):

Dieses Graubrot ist definitiv kein Schwarzbrot. Als jemand, der ursprünglich aus dem Norden kommt, wundert es mich, dass dies jemand als Schwarzbrot bezeichnen würde. Denn gerade in Norddeutschland wird Schwarzbrot seinem Namen eigentlich sehr gerecht.

Man sollte Schwarzbrot allerdings nicht unbedingt mit Pumpernickel verwechseln. Pumpernickel ist eine besonders deftige Variante, aber definitiv nicht die Definition von Schwarzbrot. Grundsätzlich handelt es sich bei Schwarzbrot um ein mindestens dunkelbraunes, wenn nicht sogar wirklich fast schwarzes, Roggenvollkornbrot. Das kann auch häufig ein Krustenbrot sein, aber eines von sehr dunkler Farbe. Nicht so ein farb- und geschmacksarmes Graubrot.

Das auf dem ersten Foto abgebildete Brot kommt dem, was ich unter Schwarzbrot verstehe, am allernächsten.

**Edit:** man sollte dazu aber vielleicht auch noch sagen, dass die Wahl des Getreides ein Brot noch nicht schwarz macht. Die Farbe kommt meistens durch Färbung mit Sirup. Die Unterscheidung zwischen echtem und falschem Schwarzbrot liegt aber immer noch in der Art des Mehls. Ein Weißbrot wird niemals ein Schwarzbrot, egal wie viel Zuckercouleur man dazu gibt.

Comment: Der Sirup - ich denke wohl meistens Rübenmolasse - ist im Pumpernickel und gibt ihm den speziellen Geschmack. Das Schwarzbrot wird schwarz vom Gerstenmalz.

Comment: Naja, kommt auf das Schwarzbrot an. Bäcker schummeln bei jeder Art Vollkornbrot ganz gern, weil es sich dunkler einfach besser verkauft. :-)

Comment: Bist Du Bäcker? Was wäre denn "schummeln" beim Vollkornbrot?

Comment: Nein, ich bin kein Bäcker, aber ich hab schon mal Brot gebacken. Normales Vollkornbrot ist von Natur aus erstaunlich hell (etwa so wie auf dem dritten Bild im Frageposting). Mit einer schönen kernig braunen Farbe verkauft es sich aber besser.

Comment: Verstehe. Ich lebe in Kanada und backe mir mein Brot hier selber - aus purer Not :-). Ich fand, daß das Vollkornweizenmehl das ich hier bekomme fast ein Schwarzbrot ergibt. Mein Roggen-Sauerteigbrot ist nicht viel dunkler.

Answer (score 1):

Südlich des Mains ist alles, was kein Weißbrot (also aus reinem, feinen Weizenmehl gebacken) ist, eben Schwarzbrot. Dort wird historisch wohl mehr Wert auf die Unterscheidung zum "luxuriösen" Weißbrot gelegt.
Und den Begriff "Graubrot" gibt es im Süden überhaupt nicht.

Comment: Hast du dafür eine Quelle oder ist das nur eine persönliche Einschätzung?

Comment: Ich bin südlich des Mains und kann der Antwort nicht zustimmen.

Answer (score -1):

Seit wann darf Schwarzbrot grau sein? Wäre mir neu.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Schwarzbrot) definiert Schwarzbrot so:

> "[überwiegend] aus Roggenmehl gebackenes dunkles Brot"

Ich esse kaum Brot, aber ich denke nicht, dass graues Brot überwiegend aus Roggen bestehen kann.

Gehst du allerdings mal in die Google Bildersuche, könnte an der Behauptung durchaus etwas dran sein.

Comment: Versucht das, die Frage zu beantworten?

Comment: Natürlich tut es das, sonst hätte ich den Post nicht erstellt.
Der Post enthält Fakten, die ich durch eine kleine Recherche zusammengestellt habe. Der Duden ist das offizielle Nachschlagewerk der deutschen Sprache.

Comment: Was hattest du denn gegooglt? Und ist dir bewusst, dass jeder in Google etwas anderes sieht?

Comment: Nein, war mir in dem Augenblick nicht bewusst. Ich sah jedenfalls auch Bilder von Graubrot, also wird ja wohl etwas dran sein. Das war aber auch aus meinem Post so ersichtlich, weswegen man es nicht unbedingt noch selbst googlen muss, um den Post zu verstehen.